# How do I separate these objects and/or combine them?

Tags: mesh

[image]Let me preface by mentioning that I have VERY limited experience with blender and similar programs. I am a complete beginner, so if there's anything I haven't mentioned, or if there's something you don't understand, please let me know.

[image: This is what the object looks like]
This is one object, note how it has many different meshes that dont touch each other and form an imaginary grid

[image: What I want]
What I want is for every mesh to be its own object, like the circled meshes show. The blue and gray are different materials, but despite this, all meshes that overlap should be combined into a single object. As you can see, some of the meshes are combinations of the elements inside the green and yellow circles.But as long as they're not touching any other meshes inside this grid they should be their own object

[image: Result]
I attempted answers to similar questions, but none have worked.Here I select the object with `A` and then `P` > `loose parts`. What I expected to happen is that all meshes that have visible space between each other would form their own objects. But what happened is that ALL FACES turned into objects despite many of them intersecting with other meshes. E.g several blue parts intersect grays, and I expected these to combine into one then: next mesh that isn't connected to any other + combine its overlaps, and then: ..., and so on. Again, Im new at this so Im sorry if Im explaining poorly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any automatic way to do what you want, so in *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to have transparency, then select with the lasso the meshes you want to separate and press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate by selection. Now these meshes are a separate object. Do the same thing for all the other meshes:

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to explain it well, but every shape that is circled (and all others) is actually multiple meshes with different materials. And the object is all of these combined... I don't know if you've played Minecraft, but think of every shape as its own block. If I split them this way, won't the overlapped meshes be split too?

Comment: from what I understand, what you're looking for is what I show but I may not have understood correctly... have your tried the method I explain?

Comment: I edited the post to add a bit more info. Hopefully it's easier to understand

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, in what way what i show doesn't give the good result?

Comment: It works! Problem is that I have like 300 of them that need to be split...

Comment: I'm afraid you don't have any other solution but maybe someone will tell...